# MongoDB tailable cursor timeout

Tags: node.js, mongodb, capped-collections

I'm looking into using mongodb for a pub-sub model. I went through different articles like http://tugdualgrall.blogspot.fr/2015/01/how-to-create-pubsub-application-with.html and https://jpaljasma.blogspot.com/2013/11/howto-mongodb-tailable-cursors-in-nodejs.html.

I had a question on the `numberOfRetries` option on the `cursor`. If i set the option `{'numberOfRetries': -1}` will this ensure that the cursor will not timeout? Which means that i'll be able to get any new documents inserted into the capped collection even if there was a long delay in a document getting added to the collection?

Thanks.

Comment: It means that it keeps retrying rathervthan showing no data found. In other words, continuous pooling.

Answer (score 0):

You can [set a cursor flag](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#addCursorFlag), specifically the `noCursorTimeout` flag:

```
let cursor = collection.find({}, ...).addCursorFlag('noCursorTimeout', true);
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. So if i use `noCursorTimeout`, then should i use the `numberOfRetries` option also?

Comment: @user320550 I think `numberOfRetries` has been deprecated, I can't find it anymore in any recent documentation.